# How to scan my project using pdsoftplan/zap-maven-plugin? I need to know without installing zap server

Tags: maven, zap

I have a zap Maven plugin in my Maven pom.xml and I have provided goals as analyze. I didn't install zap server and in pom.xml I used as `<shouldRunWithDocker>true</shouldRunWithDocker>`. Please tell me the way to scan my project using Maven plugin. It is showing error as below.

> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO]
>   [INFO] --- zap-maven-plugin:1.2.1-0:analyze (default-cli) @ IOPmsPerformanceTesting ---
>   [INFO] Starting ZAP analysis at target: https://example.com
>   [INFO] --- Validating authentication information ---
>   [INFO] Authentication information provided:  AuthenticationInfo[type=CAS,loginUrl=https://example.com,username=12,password=679,extraPostData=,loggedInRegex=,loggedOutRegex=\QLocation:[https://checkmarx.web.att.com\E](https://checkmarx.web.att.com%5CE).*,excludeFromScan=,protectedPages={https://checkmarx.web.att.com},loginRequestData=username={%username%}&password={%password%},usernameParameter=username,passwordParameter=password,httpSessionTokens=,seleniumDriver=Firefox,hostname=,realm=,port=80]
>   [INFO] The authentication information provided was successfully validated.
>   [INFO] --- Finished validating authentication information ---
>   [ERROR] Error creating a new ZAP session.
>   br.com.softplan.security.zap.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ClientApiException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
>   [ERROR] Error while trying to create the script file for CAS authentication in /zap/scripts/. The analysis will continue but CAS authentication will work only if the script file can be accessed by ZAP's Docker image (a default volume is created in /zap/scripts/).
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /zap/scripts/cas-auth.js (No such file or directory)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect its because ZAP no longer allows you to connect to the API from remote IP addresses by default. You can override this from the ZAP command line: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQapikey

Ideally the ZAP Maven Plugin should do this, but it doesnt look like thats been updated recently:/ https://github.com/pdsoftplan/zap-maven-plugin